# Why was my question relating to the speed of the Mac Appstore in China closed as "too localized, etc."?

Tags: discussion, support

You can see my question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/340719/why-is-the-mac-app-store-so-slow-in-china). I asked about whether the Mac Appstore was generally slow in China (or if it is just my connection). It was closed for being

> unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a
> small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
> extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
> the worldwide audience of the internet.

Now, I fully understand that the previous version of my question was horrendous, as it wasn't even a question, but once I edited it, it made perfect sense. I believe it had been previously closed for not being a question, but afterwards was closed for the above reason.

I also fully understand that this might not be applicable to a *worldwide* audience, but many Superuser questions are not, many are specific to certain regions or countries (I could find numerous examples).

My question is *not* only relevant to a small geographic area, as one of the commentors mentioned, China is approaching more than 500m+ internet subscribers (if we're talking about geographic area in terms of internet subscribers who can reach Superuser.com). On that note, it's not extraordinarily narrow, is it? Again, for the same reasons.

I would just like to understand why it was closed because I would really like an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Technically, the only person who can answer this is the person who performed the close (Diago). I agree that merely restricting your question to China shouldn't make it too localized, for the reasons you gave. However, you restricted it further, to Mac App Store users. I don't know how many of them there are in China, but that could be the reason. I'm not sure that app stores are on-topic for SU, but since he didn't close as off-topic, I guess that's not too relevant.

Comment: Well, I'm a bit disappointed that this happened without community involvement. The question was closed by the community, reopened by the community, just to be closed by a single binding vote again. While I think some of the "too localized" points are valid, this should have *probably* been judged by five "normal" users instead. I'm not particularly upset or worried, just my two cents. I can understand both sides of reasoning.

Comment: The main point here was that it was about store access. That pretty much is off topic.

Comment: Ok. I understand, thanks. Not hardware or software on a computer.

Comment: It is also localised in time (i.e. even if the Mac App Store, as compared to other websites/services, is slow for the entirety of China, it might not be tomorrow), and (as Diago said below) is unlikely to be answerable by anyone who doesn’t work for the Mac App Store, your ISP, or the Chinese government.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking about traffic and speed to an app store and then narrowing it down further to location gives you two points in the "too localised" column.

This can be reclosed as off topic if you prefer.

Comment: @kalaracey After careful consideration I have nothing further to add. The question is not solving a problem, it's asking us to theorise on something that can't officially be answered by anyone except the Chinese ISP's. It is also very specific to only users in China, and doesn't really fit the SuperUser mold. I stand by my decision to close it.

Comment: Alright, thank you Diago, random, Lord Torgamus, and slhck for your input. I'll avoid asking such theoretical questions. But just because it is specific to a certain country / region (USA/Europe/China) doesn't mean that it should be closed / doesn't fit the SuperUser model. There are plenty of questions that relate just to a certain country that haven't been closed; all you need to do is search "USA" or "Europe" in the search bar. But, thank you anyways.

Comment: @kalaracey Due to the confusion around this close, I have now closed it as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, with the [recent change of scope on the Ask Different site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) - Super User could migrate questions like this to out site since we are explicitly welcoming questions about the Apple services offered under the iTunes Connect umbrella.

This specific item may be too old to migrate, but please ping me on my site's chat room if you want to re-ask this question on a site where it would be more on-topic.

Comment: Oh well! Too late now. Already moved back to the US. Thanks anyways :-)